# Convert C# dictionary with delegate values to its VB.NET equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, delegates, code-translation

I require some help to understand how can I translate this kind of dictionary entries that uses a delegate as value, from C# to VB.NET:

```
using LookupT = 
    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, System.Func<BBCodeNode, bool, string>>;

public delegate string HtmlRendererCallback(BBCodeNode Node, 
                                            bool ThrowOnError, 
                                            object LookupTable);

static readonly LookupT[] convertLookup = 
    new Dictionary<string, HtmlRendererCallback>
    {
        { "b", DirectConvert }
    }.ToArray();

public static string DirectConvert(BBCodeNode Node, 
                                   bool ThrowOnError, 
                                   object LookupTable)
{
    //...
}
```

What I tried is this translation below which will not work, the debugger marks the function name as error in the dictionary entry ( `{"b", DirectConvert()}` ) asking me to pass the proper arguments to the `DirectConvert` function:

```
Imports LookupT = 
    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, System.Func(Of BBCodeNode, Boolean, String))

Public Delegate Function HtmlRendererCallback(node As BBCodeNode, 
                                              throwOnError As Boolean, 
                                              lookupTable As Object) As String

Shared ReadOnly convertLookup As LookupT() = 
    New Dictionary(Of String, HtmlRendererCallback)() From 
        {
            {"b", DirectConvert()}
        }.ToArray()

Public Shared Function DirectConvert(node As BBCodeNode, 
                                     throwOnError As Boolean,
                                     lookupTable As Object) As String
' ...
End sub
```

...however, in the C# code if I'm not wrong it seems like it is not specifying at all any argument to the function, so... it is confusing me.

Comment: Sorry everybody, I messed up the codes when I were copying and pasting them in my question the C# and the VB.NET codes without noticing what I wrote so the codes were messed, I fixed it. Now I can understand the reason for that closure vote, but sure now will be clear the question. sorry again for my foolishness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this:

```
    Public Delegate Function HtmlRendererCallback(ByVal node As BBCodeNode, ByVal throwOnError As Boolean, ByVal lookupTable As Object) As String
    Shared convertMeth As HtmlRendererCallback = AddressOf DirectConvert
    Shared ReadOnly convertLookup As ILookup(Of String, HtmlRendererCallback) = New Dictionary(Of String, HtmlRendererCallback)() From {
        {"b", convertMeth},
        {"c", convertMeth},
        {"d", convertMeth}
    }

    Public Shared Function DirectConvert(ByVal node As BBCodeNode, ByVal throwOnError As Boolean, ByVal lookupTable As Object) As String
        DirectConvert = ""
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, however your suggested solution did not fixed the problem. I still have the same error at design time on the dictionary entry, it asks for the arguments to pass to **convertMeth**.

Comment: I am not seeing in design time. Could you please check one more time?

Comment: Could you please cross check the "DirectConvert" function declaration with mine and yours?

Comment: Yes of course, I'm sure: http://i.imgur.com/dB4XtJL.png  I'm using all the members that you declared (as is) in your answer.

Comment: Is ToArray() is required?

Comment: And also do not use "()" after "convertMeth".

Comment: Ouch, my bad for using parenthesis, was a silly thing like that. now seems it will work removing the parenthesis. please give me 10-15 mins to test it and then I'll mark the answer as accepted. Thanks for all!